Mind your P's & Q's
Here is a numbered sequence of words/phrases.
Where should SESQUIPEDALIAN (or the title) fit in this list?

ZIPPER
PEPPER
MONEY
SNIPPY
PRIMED
PIPPED
SNAPPED
POUND PUPPY
PARADROPPED
QUASI-POPULAR PEOPLE
... (sequence continues without termination)

Note: The specific words given are somewhat arbitrary and could be replaced by other words. The goal is to find how the words map to the ordinals.
Not all words are in the sequence. For example, CLIPPER could go at position 1, but PUZZLING and SUM do not fit anywhere.
Hints:

 General trivia type knowledge is required, although to many it will be trivial. The sequence represented here is not the counting numbers... but it should not be difficult to guess what sequence it is.


Does the word-property tag apply?  or letters tag?

@JLee Possibly. If anything, it may need an enigmatic tag.

By fit in the list do you mean replace another one of the words?

@pdt you will know what to do if you get far enough

Hmm any hints possible?

@BeastlyGerbil I second that this puzzle has really kicked my ass. Been mainly focusing on it on and off whenever I had any time to do any puzzles…still nothing and believe me I have tried everything under the sun!!

I added 4 more examples, but I think more hints are overkill at this point; there is plenty here to discover, though some will find it harder than others.

Is it possible that the word "Saqqara" would fall somewhere between #20-29, assuming all unmet conditions to make it onto the list were met?

@blueherring no, and a correct solution will be very obviously the intended solution

I think this question for us clues

 prime number amounts of US currency, clued by: P = Penny, N = Nickel, D = Dime, Q = Quarter

The words map to

 2 ZIPPER - 2 Pennies
 3 PEPPER - 3 Pennies
5 MONEY - Nickel
 7 SNIPPY - Nickel and 2 Pennies
 11 PRIMED - Dime and Penny
 13 PIPPED - Dime and 3 Pennies
 17 SNAPPED - Dime, Nickel and 2 Pennies
 19 POUND PUPPY - Dime, Nickel and 4 Pennies
 23 PARADROPPED - 2 Dimes and 3 Pennies
 29 QUASI-POPULAR PEOPLE - Quarter and 4 Pennies

Some words SUM and PUZZLING do not appear on the list as

 SUM has 0 value and PUZZLING is 6 which is non-prime

SESQUIPEDALIAN (or the title Mind your P's & Q's) should fit in the

 list of primes 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, ...
 SESQUIPEDALIAN - Quarter, Dime, Nickel and Penny - 41 in the 13th row
 Mind your P's & Q's - Quarter, Dime, Nickel, Penny - in the same row!

The title may also clue

 p and q are notation for prime numbers in mathematics, and they are US coin first letters.


You got it! Did you use the "hidden" clues or just a good guess?

@Amoz - The hints helped to change to thinking of an infinite non-whole number sequence, and involving info which may be even easier for some. I may still be missing some nuggets. A sterling puzzle!

Are the hidden hints that “MONEY”, “PRIME(D)”, and “SUM” are all specified words?
